# Azure VM won't boot - Error is 'Fatal error C0000034 applying update operation 63 of 82641'

Tags: azure, virtual-machine, boot, recover

VM is set to start every morning at 8am. This morning I got the following error : -

'**Fatal error C0000034 applying update operation 63 of 82641**' in the Boot Diagnostics section in the VM Console

Every previous occurrence I found googling the error did not relate to an Azure VM but a standalone laptop. All of these suggest starting from a different partition or rescue disk which is not possible in my case.

Tried re-starting the VM

Redeploying the VM

Resizing the VM

Whatever I try I still can't RDP to the VM.

I can't restore the C: drive as I can't connect to the VM to do it.

Any ideas how I can recover from this or rescue the VM ? All greatly appreciated.

Thanks,

Dan.

Comment: I've managed no to resolve this so will post the Solution in here for anyone else 

Found the error in the Microsoft Docs here :-

Answer (score 1):

I've managed no to resolve this so will post the Solution in here for anyone else

Found the error in the Microsoft Docs here :-
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/troubleshoot/azure/virtual-machines/troubleshoot-stuck-updating-boot-error?WT.mc_id=Portal-Microsoft_Azure_Support

This advised taking a copy of the OS Disk and attaching it as a Data Disk to a 'Rescue VM'

Running the following Powershell command against the Disk in

dism /image::\ /get-packages > c:\temp\Patch_level.txt

Open the file , scroll to the bottom and look for updates that are Install Pending or Uninstall Pending

Running the following Powershell command

dism /Image::\ /Remove-Package /PackageName:     where PackageName is the Package Identity in the text file

Detach the now repaired OS Disk from the Repair VM and Attach it to the Original VM

Start the VM - it may take a while to start.

With the oncoming tide of Managed Disks, I don't suppose there will be much call for this solution , but it's here if anyone needs it.